# JPA, distinct, order by, null values and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode

Tags: mysql, jpa, sql-mode

I have a JPA query structured like this:

```
SELECT distinct item
FROM ... 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

I'm using MySQL 8 and because I'm using the ORDER BY clause to sort by item properties, area name country name and brand name) I was getting this error:

```
Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'db.country4_.name' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

I had to include the order by fields in the SELECT:

```
SELECT distinct item, item.area.name, item.country.name, item.brand.name 
FROM ... 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY ...
```

The problem is that doing so the query now doesn't select anymore the items that have country == NULL.

Beside removing the distinct or changing the `sql-mode`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html says:

> Consider the case of a table t with three columns c1, c2, and c3 that contains these rows:
>
> ```
> c1 c2 c3
> 1  2  A
> 3  4  B
> 1  2  C
> ```
>
> Suppose that we execute the following query, expecting the results to
>   be ordered by c3:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2 FROM t ORDER BY c3;
> ```

Should the result be:

```
c1 c2
1  2
3  4
```

Or should it be:

```
c1 c2
3  4
1  2
```

If it ordered by `c3`, it should be the first example. But DISTINCT is implemented by copying the result rows to a temporary table, sorting that table, and eliminating duplicates. If `c3` is not part of the select-list, then it is not included in the temporary table. But if `c3` is included as part of the select-list, so it's in the temporary table, then it affects the DISTINCT operation.

The documentation goes on:

> To prevent this problem, a query that has DISTINCT and ORDER BY is
>   rejected as invalid if any ORDER BY expression does not satisfy at
>   least one of these conditions:
>
> - The expression is equal to one in the select list
> - All columns referenced by the expression and belonging to the query's
>     selected tables are elements of the select list